# Deleting the record in child reference table dynamically before deleting the parent

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table with primary key which is being used as reference key in several, so i am trying to build a script wherein it will first delete all the records in child table and then the parent key dynamically.

Note :- If there is any constraint on child table being referenced by other tables that also we need to take care of.

Comment: You might want to consider changing all your foreign keys to ON DELETE CASCADE, so what you describe would happen automatically when deleting a parent. More on this here: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_foreign_key_on_delete_cascade.htm.

Comment: If you don't want to do it the normal and easy way as suggested by @Thorsten Kettner, you can make use of the tables DBA_CONSTRAINTS and DBA_CONS_COLUMNS to get the primary key name and columns of parent table and foreign key name and columns of the child tables. Then you can write a block to delete the data from child tables first and then from the parent table. Doing it this way is a waste of time.

Comment: At this point of time we cannot go with table alteration, as of now we are not having On_DELETE_CASCADE on our key. The problem here is suppose at one level i will be able to find all the tables referencing the particular primary key... But the referencing tables again can be referenced by the other table. SO it could be N level, so was looking for some way wherein it will delete the all dependencies